# Python requests library gives garbled response even though curl and browser give coherent text

Tags: python, curl

Here is my problem:

1. Using a Browser, I can download a text file with this content:

URL: protocol://URL/otrs/nph-genericinterface.pl/Webservice/GenericTicketConnectorREST/Ticket/12621?UserLogin=P_6669&Password=XXXXXX

> HTTP/1.1 200 OK Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
> Content-Length: 669 Connection: close
>
> {"ConfigItem":[{"CurInciState":"Operational","ConfigItemID":"245767","InciStateType":"operational","CurInciStateType":"operational","Number":"3266000189","CreateBy":"3","CurDeplState":"Production","LastVersionID":"463432","DeplState":"Production","CreateTime":"2017-01-18
> 10:09:01","DefinitionID":"466","VersionID":"463432","DeplStateType":"productive","CIXMLData":{"FilaResponsavel":"","type":"Active-active","tipo-inventario":"","VIPaddress":"sepap.camara.gov.br","id-inventario":"D0E7907294A0402C9AB0C1AD3D4C4704","Description":"Teste.","link-inventario":""},"Class":"Cluster
> Group","InciState":"Operational","CurDeplStateType":"productive","Name":"Cluster-Sepap"}]}

2. Using curl:

curl -k 'protocol://URL/otrs/nph-genericinterface.pl/Webservice/GenericTicketConnectorREST/Ticket/12621?UserLogin=P_6669&Password=XXXXXX'

> {"Ticket":[{"EscalationTimeWorkingTime":"-382512","Age":846912,"PriorityID":"3","EscalationDestinationTime":"1483993892","ServiceID":"","EscalationDestinationIn":"106h
> 15m","SolutionTimeWorkingTime":"-357312","Type":"Unclassified","Responsible":"root@localhost","SolutionTimeDestinationDate":"2017-01-10
> 11:31:32","StateID":"4","ResponsibleID":"1","ChangeBy":"1","EscalationTime":-843312,"SolutionTimeDestinationTime":"1484055092","EscalationDestinationDate":"2017-01-09
> 18:31:32","OwnerID":"1","Changed":"2017-01-09
> 17:31:34","FirstResponseTimeWorkingTime":"-382512","RealTillTimeNotUsed":"0","GroupID":"1","Owner":"root@localhost","CustomerID":"CENTRO
> DE INFORMÁTICA","TypeID":"1","Created":"2017-01-09
> 17:31:32","Priority":"3
> normal","FirstResponseTimeEscalation":1,"UntilTime":0,"EscalationUpdateTime":"0","QueueID":"1","Queue":"Postmaster","State":"open","Title":"Ticket#3","FirstResponseTimeDestinationDate":"2017-01-09
> 18:31:32","CreateBy":"1","TicketID":"12621","StateType":"open","UnlockTimeout":"0","EscalationResponseTime":"1483993892","FirstResponseTimeDestinationTime":"1483993892","EscalationSolutionTime":"1484055092","LockID":"1","ArchiveFlag":"n","TicketNumber":"30004295","SolutionTime":-782112,"CreateTimeUnix":"1483990292","Lock":"unlock","SolutionTimeEscalation":1,"SLAID":"","CustomerUserID":"P_7029","FirstResponseTime":-843312}]}

3. Using Python:

   ```
   #!/usr/bin/env python
   # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

   import requests
   usuario = {'UserLogin':'P_6669','Password':'XXXXXX'}
   headers = {'accept': 'application/json','content-type' : 'applicatio/json'}

   ret = requests.get('protocol://URL/otrs/nph-genericinterface.pl/Webservice/GenericTicketConnectorREST/Ticket/12621', verify=False, params=usuario)

   print "URL: " + ret.url
   print "Status Code: " + str(ret.status_code)
   print "Raw: " + str(ret.raw)
   try:
           print "Text: " + str(ret.text)
   except:
           print "TEXT: ERRO!"

   print "Headers: " + str(ret.headers)
   try:
           print "Json: " + ret.json()
   except:
           print "Json: ERRO!"
   print "Content: " + ret.content
   ```

Resultado:

URL: protocol://URL/otrs/nph-genericinterface.pl/Webservice/GenericTicketConnectorREST/Ticket/12621?UserLogin=P_6669&Password=XXXXXX

Status Code: 200

Raw: urllib3.response.HTTPResponse object at 0x7f8e86628510

TEXT: ERRO!

Headers: CaseInsensitiveDict({})

Json: ERRO!

Content: �����$��6�u��|A�^......... A lot of trash here ....

I already tried a lot of combinations with `requests.get`, `requests.post`, `httplib2.Http`. Always I got this error.

Why does this happen?

Comment: what's the exception that happens when you get the `TEXT: ERRO!`?

Comment: The "trash" is probably due to `gzip` encoding.

Comment: Error with TEXT: UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\ufffd' in position 1: ordinal not in range(128)

Answer (score 12):

Removing "br" from the `Accept-Encoding` of request headers, helped me to resolve this.

```
headers = {
   "Accept":"text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8",
   "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
   "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.9",
   "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/67.0.3396.99 Safari/537.36",
}
```

Comment: same happend to me today

Answer (score 3):

How about something like this:

```
import gzip
print gzip.decompress(ret.content)
```

Alternatively:

```
import zlib
print zlib.decompress(ret.content, 16+zlib.MAX_WBITS)
```

Comment: It works! 

import zlib
print zlib.decompress(ret.content, 16+zlib.MAX_WBITS)

Answer (score 1):

1) With my code, the problem is the gzip response...

It works with

```
    import zlib
    print zlib.decompress(ret.content, 16+zlib.MAX_WBITS)
```

2) But, a friend found a better solution:

```
   #!/usr/bin/env python

   import json
   from pprint import pprint
   from urllib2 import urlopen, Request, URLError, HTTPError

   userdata = {
     'UserLogin': 'p_xxxxx',
     'Password' : 'xxxxx'
   }

   url = 'protocol://url/otrs/nph-genericinterface.pl/Webservice/GenericTicketConnectorREST'

   try:
       session_request = Request(url + '/Session', json.dumps(userdata))
       session_id      = urlopen(session_request).read()

       ticket_search   = Request(url + '/Ticket/12621', session_id)
       ticket_response = urlopen(ticket_search).read()

       pprint(json.loads(ticket_response))
   except HTTPError, e:
       print e
   except URLError, e:
       print e.reason
```

I dont know why urllib2.urlopen can undestand and decode gzip and requests cant...

Comment: In http://docs.python-requests.org/en/v0.10.7/user/quickstart/: `... The gzip and deflate transfer-encodings are automatically decoded for you. ...`

Answer (score 0):

You might need to install `brotli` or `brotlicffi` package to allow Requests to correctly decompress this site.

Check your response for the 'Content-Encoding' header. If it's 'br' than try installing the package.

```
print(html_doc.headers['Content-Encoding'])
```

> When the brotli or brotlicffi packages are installed,
> urllib3.util.make_headers() inserts ',br' in the Accept-Encoding
> header and decodes br from the answers.

(https://github.com/psf/requests/pull/5783)

Alternatively to removing 'br' from your request 'Accept-Encoding' headers, as [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10041437/krishna-sankara)